# Server spec priority for IIS server and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis

My factory has 2 servers, I will need 1 server for IIS and another for SQL Server.

This factory production run 24 hours and has constant transaction.

Currently EVERYTHING is on Server A. Of course this is causing some performance issue.

So I plan to have IIS and SQL Server on different servers.

I not sure I should use which server as IIS and another as SQL Server 2008 R2.

<= Server A =>

- 2 CPU (2.40 ghz 2.39 ghz), total 16 cores
- 8 GB

<= Server B =>

- 1 CPU (2.40 ghz 2.39 ghz), total 8 cores
- 4 GB

this is my first question, so I not sure am I asking in a correct way.
Thanks.

Comment: You disk setup for the database server is going to be much more critical. For example adding separate RAID arrays for logs and historical data. It is possible to split your tables in a database over several arrays thus giving you great performance. Details the servers a bit more and we can have a look.

Comment: Both servers are RAID.
This factory is a small-medium size company, so we don't have luxuries upgrade on it.
Is the CPU cores more important to SQL Server or IIS server?
Within next few weeks we will upgrade the RAM (+ 8 GB ram).
I had set my database Recovery Model to no log files. 
Is the log file really important? I never found any use of it except it take a huge amount of spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that SQL should get the "big" server since it's processing is almost always more intensive than IIS / App processing.

Longer answer is that, without detailed analysis and performance testing under load, your allocation and sizing of the boxes is just a shot in the dark. The best practice would be this: talk your factory owner into buying a single big server and install VM ware on it. That will allow you to split that server into 2 (or more) virtual servers you can configure the way you want. Then, once you get your IIS and SQL servers up and running in a production scenario, you can study how the stress is distributed across the servers. Then you can use VMware to "tune" your servers, allocating more processing and memory where needed.

If, for instance, you find that your IIS/app server is running at 99% mem / 99% cpu, you can quickly allocate more cores and memory to the IIS side of the server quite easily, reboot (takes l0 seconds) and you've successfully performance tuned your server array.

Comment: I never know asking questions about server is off topic.
I had studied from few others StackOverflow link before I ask question.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984951/iis-and-sql-on-same-machine-best-performance)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401834/when-can-i-host-iis-and-sql-server-on-the-same-machine/1401866#1401866)
Sorry for not knowing the rules before this.

Comment: Wee Yik Gan ... your question is off topic, but you still got an answer to work with. Good luck.